# Disambiguating RESTful services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing, restful-url

I have used WCF extensively in previous projects. Lately, I have been exploring the use of ASP.NET Web API in creating RESTful services. After studying the DO's and DONT's of RESTful services and even trying it practically, I have a rather straightforward question.

Suppose I have a `UsersController` (inheriting `ApiController`) where I NEED to have 3 GET-type action methods:

```
    GetUsers()
    GetUserById(string id)
    GetUserByName(string name)
```

Suppose I also have the following route in *WebApiConfig*

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Users",
        routeTemplate: "api/users/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "users", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

`http://localhost:<port>/api/users` would obviously invoke `GetUsers()`

The problem comes when I need to invoke either of the two action methods that take a single parameter.

I would like

`http://localhost:<port>/api/users/5c6fe209-821e-475f-920d-1af0f3f52a82` to invoke `GetUserById(string id)`

and

`http://localhost:<port>/api/users/jdoe` to invoke `GetUserByName(string name)`

What I expect will happen instead is that I'll either get an error or only the first action method will be invoked for either case.

Since introducing the action on the route to disambiguate is considered as a deviation from pure RESTful services, how do I make the different URLs invoke the respective action method? I have scoured the web and most examples of RESTful services (by purists) stop at a first action method to retrieve everything and a second to retrieve a single item.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using more specific constrained routes.  The example below is similar to what you are trying to achieve:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ById",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetById" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ByName",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetByName", },
    constraints: new { name = @"\w+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "All",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetAll", }
);
```

The constraints object you pass to MapHttpRoute specifies constraints in the form of regex for the different URL parameters.  In this example, for the ById route we only match if the id parameter is a number.  We only match ByName if the name parameter is a string of alpha characters.  We match All on no parameters.  Note the "+" on each of the regex specifies no empty values.  Routes are matched in the order they are defined, so you should put the least specific rules below more specific rules.

In your case, you will need to find or write a regular expression that matches the GUID format you are using and constrain your ById route to match this expression. You'll then want to define your ByName route below accepting any string.  Because it's below, it will only get called if the input string is not a GUID.

I should also add that if you have not worked with MVC routes before, they are very specific.  You'll notice that the name of my parameter is {id} for ById and {name} for ByName.  It is important these parameters match the exact name of your input parameter on your controller method since it's this that is used by the router build the method call.  Even if you have only a single parameter on an action, if the name is not mapped correctly you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Just thinking, if you go about it this way, will you not have sacrificed the fluency that the RESTful services are intended to have?

Comment: Actually, if its to get this complicated, would it not be better or easier to just force the caller to supply the action name?

Comment: 2 months later... I don't think it's /that/ complicated personally. But to answer, it's simpler to consume a service with an implicit filter action, but more difficult to write server side.  You are just moving the complexity to the client if you choose the other approach.  What I will say is that if you had a situation where you had a user who's name was a digit (unlikely with this example but possible for other entites) your names would be interpreted as IDs, so requiring the filter method be explicitly specified is the best approach probably.

Comment: Actually, the most ReST approach is probably to user the /users/{id} method, but when searching for a user by name you would use /users/?name={name}.  This is kinda assuming that name is not unique.  I guess what I'm saying is, anything you put in the URL should uniquely identify that entity, whereas anything that is not unique should be a query parameter on the set.  Users is probably one of the rarer examples of a situation where two attributes (name and id) are unique, in which case I would debate with myself in circles until I don't care anymore and it's home time.